# How can I set it so a file in a form doesn't have to be uploaded to insert the rest of the form data into mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have searched everywhere for days on this but can't seem to figure out a solution.

I am building a user blog in PHP/mySQL.

I want to allow the user to upload a new blog post (AKA. a headline, a blog and a photo).

Everything works perfectly, except for if they do not select a photo to upload, the script will not parse and nothing will be inserted into the database.

I have posted the parsing script file.

How can I insert the information in the database, even with no photo selected?

```
//Get photo details
?><?php 
if (isset($_FILES["blog_photo"]["name"]) && $_FILES["blog_photo"]["tmp_name"] != ""){
  $fileName = $_FILES["blog_photo"]["name"];
  $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["blog_photo"]["tmp_name"];
  $fileType = $_FILES["blog_photo"]["type"];
  $fileSize = $_FILES["blog_photo"]["size"];
  $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["blog_photo"]["error"];
  $kaboom = explode(".", $fileName);
  $fileExt = end($kaboom);
  list($width, $height) = getimagesize($fileTmpLoc);
  if($width < 10 || $height < 10){
    header("location: ../message.php?msg=ERROR: That image has no dimensions");
    exit(); 
  }

  //Restrict photo uploads
  $db_file_name = rand(100000000000,999999999999).".".$fileExt;
  if($fileSize > 3048576) {
    header("location: ../message.php?msg=ERROR: Your image file was larger than 3mb");
    exit();}    
  if (!preg_match("/\.(gif|jpg|png)$/i", $fileName) ) {
    header("location: ../message.php?msg=ERROR: Your image file was not jpg, gif or png type");
    exit();
  } else if ($fileErrorMsg == 1) {
    header("location: ../message.php?msg=ERROR: An unknown error occurred");
    exit();
  }

  $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "../user/$log_id/$db_file_name");
  if ($moveResult != true) {
    header("location: ../message.php?msg=ERROR: File upload failed");
    exit();
  }
  include_once("../php_includes/image_resize.php");
  $target_file = "../user/$log_id/$db_file_name";
  $resized_file = "../user/$log_id/$db_file_name";
  $wmax = 600;
  $hmax = 400;
  img_resize($target_file, $resized_file, $wmax, $hmax, $fileExt);

  //define variables from form to insert into database
  $bh =$_POST['blog_heading_a'];
  $bt =$_POST['blog_text_a'];
  $u =$_POST['user_id'];
  $a =$_POST['blog_photo'];

  //insert into database
  $insertSQL ="INSERT INTO blog (blog_heading, blog_photo, blog_day, blog_text, user_id) VALUES ('$bh','$db_file_name',NOW(),'$bt','$u')";
  mysql_select_db($database_database_conn, $database_conn);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $database_conn) or die(mysql_error());
  header("location: ../user.php?u=$log_id");
  exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: I thought the "if (isset) would take care of it, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: You should know that your script is extremely insecure.  You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and **you will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Use prepared/parameterized queries to avoid this problem entirely.  Also, your redirection method is flawed.  URLs as values of the `Location:` header must be a full URL.  While relative paths often work, they violate the standards.  Also, you must encode reserved characters in the URL, such as spaces as `%20`.

Comment: What do you mean "the script will not parse"? Parsing the script has nothing to do with the input data.

Comment: The `isset()` says that if there's no upload file, nothing in this script will be done. If you indented your code, you'd probably have recognized this immediately.

Comment: @Brad The standard is being revised to allow relative paths in Location, since it's common practice and all browsers support it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the database insert outside the `if()`, since that code only gets executed when a photo has been uploaded.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_FILES["blog_photo"]["name"]) && $_FILES["blog_photo"]["tmp_name"] != ""){
  $fileName = $_FILES["blog_photo"]["name"];
  $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["blog_photo"]["tmp_name"];
  $fileType = $_FILES["blog_photo"]["type"];
  $fileSize = $_FILES["blog_photo"]["size"];
  $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["blog_photo"]["error"];
  $kaboom = explode(".", $fileName);
  $fileExt = end($kaboom);
  list($width, $height) = getimagesize($fileTmpLoc);
  if($width < 10 || $height < 10){
    header("location: ../message.php?msg=ERROR: That image has no dimensions");
    exit(); 
  }

  //Restrict photo uploads
  $db_file_name = rand(100000000000,999999999999).".".$fileExt;
  if($fileSize > 3048576) {
    header("location: ../message.php?msg=ERROR: Your image file was larger than 3mb");
    exit();}    
  if (!preg_match("/\.(gif|jpg|png)$/i", $fileName) ) {
    header("location: ../message.php?msg=ERROR: Your image file was not jpg, gif or png type");
    exit();
  } else if ($fileErrorMsg == 1) {
    header("location: ../message.php?msg=ERROR: An unknown error occurred");
    exit();
  }

  $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "../user/$log_id/$db_file_name");
  if ($moveResult != true) {
    header("location: ../message.php?msg=ERROR: File upload failed");
    exit();
  }
  include_once("../php_includes/image_resize.php");
  $target_file = "../user/$log_id/$db_file_name";
  $resized_file = "../user/$log_id/$db_file_name";
  $wmax = 600;
  $hmax = 400;
  img_resize($target_file, $resized_file, $wmax, $hmax, $fileExt);

} else {
  $db_file_name = '';
}

//define variables from form to insert into database
$bh =$_POST['blog_heading_a'];
$bt =$_POST['blog_text_a'];
$u =$_POST['user_id'];
$a =$_POST['blog_photo'];

//insert into database
$insertSQL ="INSERT INTO blog (blog_heading, blog_photo, blog_day, blog_text, user_id) VALUES ('$bh','$db_file_name',NOW(),'$bt','$u')";
mysql_select_db($database_database_conn, $database_conn);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $database_conn) or die(mysql_error());
header("location: ../user.php?u=$log_id");
exit();

?>
```